# Show $H^1_{dR}(U, \mathbb R) \cong \mathbb R$, where $U$ is the punctured plane

Tags: homology-cohomology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

> Let $U := \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ be the punctured plane and $\gamma$ the counter clockwise once traversed unit circle. Show that the map
>   $$\tag{1} [α] \mapsto  \int^{2 \pi}_{0} \alpha_{\gamma (t)}(\gamma' (t))dt $$
>   between the first deRham cohomology group $H^1_{dR}(U, R)$ and $\mathbb R$ is a linear isomorphism.

**Remark**: In a separate [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239495/integrating-alpha-in-h1-dr-along-a-closed-curve-is-well-defined) I asked if the mapping $(1)$ is well-defined.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**So**, the first cohomology group is the closed forms in $\Omega^{1}_{dR}$ modulo the exact forms.

And we know that $\gamma$ is the once traversed unit circle (which may be parameterized by $cos^{2}(\theta) + sin^{2}(\theta) = 1$)

Comment: So if $\alpha=df$ is exact, what is the integral around the unit circle? (Hint: Chain rule.)

Comment: Hmm... I feel like I'm missing something here (due to your suggestion of the chain rule and the simplicity of my argument) but would it not just be f(2*$\pi$)-f(0)?

Comment: Sure, @Kyle. But you get that by integrating $df_{\alpha(t)}(\alpha'(t)) = (f\circ\alpha)'(t)\,dt$. :)

Comment: Of of course! I see that, so how does this allow me to show that the coset above is indeed a linear isomorphism. What exactly am I looking to show?

Comment: So this shows the map is well-defined. Now can you show that you map *onto* $\Bbb R$ (so that the map is surjective) and that if you map to $0$, then the form $\alpha$ is exact (so that the map is injective)?

Comment: I'm a bit fuzzy on the showing the map is surjective to the real line. For the mapping to 0 would we simply show that at 0 the exterior derivative d$\alpha$ is 0? Since the exterior derivative of an exact form is 0 -- since d$\alpha$ = d(df) and two consecutive applications of the 'd' operator produce 0 (If I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Kyle, here is an outline of what you need to do:

(1) Find a (reasonably famous) *closed* $1$-form $\omega$ on $U$ whose integral around the unit circle is not $0$ (it may well be $2\pi$). How does using $\omega$ show that the map is surjective?

(2) Say $C$ is the unit circle oriented counterclockwise. Suppose $\displaystyle\int_C\alpha = 0$. You must show that $\alpha$ is exact. The idea is to define $f(x) = \displaystyle\int_{(1,0)}^x \alpha$ and show that this is well-defined, independent of path from $(1,0)$ to $x$ [you may need a little bit of hand-waving here to see that any two paths in $U$ differ by a path that is "essentially" some number of times of going around the unit circle — see if you can make this more precise]. Then you need to know or check that $df = \alpha$. Perhaps you did this in class.

Comment: Oh!! You're talking about d$\theta$ = $ \frac{-ydx + xdy}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$. The fact that we're dealing with the punctured plane and d$\theta$ isn't defined at the origin should have been a huge giveaway! That makes sense. And a surjective map (also known as *onto*) is one which maps every element of the codomain to at least one element of the domain (with 1 element defining bijection) so based on the periodic nature of the theta (or argument) function we can say that every element of the codomain is mapped to at least an element of the domain?

Comment: You've got mappings going backwards in this. But if $d\theta$ integrates to $2\pi$, what integrates to $r\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: Well I would imagine dr. Right? Because: $\int^{r}_{0} dr = r$

Comment: @Kyle: No, no. You have to still integrate around the unit circle!!

Comment: Well if we're integrating from 0 to 2$\pi$ then the form we would need would need to be something like $\frac{r}{2\pi}d\theta$ That's all I can think of.. I feel like I'm missing something though. (Certainly wouldn't be the first time)

Comment: No, that's what I wanted you to realize. So that gets surjectivity. Now you have to finish the injectivity, as I discussed earlier.

Comment: Okay, how exactly does that get surjectivity? If you don't mind me asking. We say there's some form, say, $d\Phi = \frac{r}{2\pi}d\theta$ which has the property that when integrated around the unit circle gives us r. r (being the radius) is a constant value so if we were to traverse the unit circle twice (from 0 to 4$\pi$) we would get $2r$ so does that prove surjectivity? That as we continue to wind around we keep getting numbers which are larger and larger (hence never getting the same number twice)?

Comment: $r$ has nothing to do with radius. I just picked a letter for an arbitrary element of $\Bbb R$ and you gave me a closed (but not exact — despite the misleading $d\theta$ notation) form whose integral around the unit circle is that real number.

Comment: So then can we say (based on amt of revolutions) that we can produce any element of $\mathbb{R}$ from the integral around the unit circle of this form? Thus showing surjectivity?

Comment: Revolutions? Going around the unit circle more times (which isn't even allowed by the definition of the mapping) would only give you $\Bbb Z$ times the original integral, not $\Bbb R$.